# Eclipse: export to .jar AND include resource files (ANT)

Tags: eclipse, ant, executable-jar, java-6

Our project in eclipse approximately shows the following folders:

```
application
    - src
    - JRE System Library [1.6]
    - Referenced Libraries
    - lib
    - rsc
```

In our project, we would like to use File > Export... > Executable JAR

Well that works fine, with some exception: If we want to run our application.jar, we still need to copy the folder rsc/ in the same location as application.jar.

In rsc/, we have other folders for separation of the different parts.
Basically, we load the pieces using the code (well a bit altered, but the path style is correct)

```
strUrl = "file:rsc/properties/Constants.properties";
url = new URL(strUrl);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
```

I could rightclick on rsc/ > Build Path > Use as Source Folder.

But this doesn't work either because eclipse doesn't automatically copy the rsc folder into the bin/-folder. And then we cannot run it anymore from terminal (not packaged into jar)

**EDIT**: why is eclipse unable to handle this correctly? Why does it have problems with "nested" output folders? In the Source-tab of the Build Path dialog, I could easily add the rsc/-folder with the output folder set to bin/rsc/, but it doesn't seem to be able to put nested folders...

---

**EDIT 2**: Now I've been able to create an xml-file to build the stuff with ant, and somehow managed to include the rsc-folder right into the jar. Still doesn't run due to the same errors. Do I really need to check the resources paths whether they're in a JAR or not? The JAR's content is now the following:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
configurator/
controller/
editor/
gui/
logic/
networking/
rsc/
rsc/gamesettings/
rsc/levels/
rsc/pics/
rsc/properties/
util/
```

but Java still hates me and throws `java.io.FileNotFoundException: rsc/properties/Constants.properties` with a stacktrace of around 100 lines.

---

anybody an idea how to do it? thx & regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you mark `rsc` as a source folder Eclipse will copy its contents to the output directory. Or you could just move `rsc` under `src` if you want to group the resources in the output.

Then you can use `Class.getResource("/properties/Constants.properties")` or `Class.getResource("/rsc/properties/Constants.properties")` and it will work regardless if your app is packaged as a jar or running from the source.

As a sidenote, the `file:` protocol works only with normal files, to access files inside the jar you'd have to use something like `new URL("jar:file:app.jar!/rsc/properties/Constants.properties")`.

Comment: Yes. This was the solution, but marking rsc/ as src-folder in eclipse doesn't do the job. Another student led me right to the same solution. The problem was that we had to use Class.getResource("..."), the path prepended with a `/`. thx and regards

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `Class#getResource()`? There's no such static method in `Class` class.

Comment: @m0skit0 The method is not static, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Dan Berindei can you answer my question pls ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685537/including-source-files-in-runnable-jar-file

Comment: @Talib there is a non-static method `getResource(String)`

Answer (score 4):

You could try: In the Java Build Path dialog, go to the Libraries tab and select "Add Class Folder...". Select `rsc` from the Class Folder Selection dialog. The contents of the `rsc` directory will now be included in the executable jar file.

(Note that rsc itself won't be included, so you may have to add a new subdirectory under rsc to make the directory structure in the jar right.)

Comment: thx for your response. Well yes, that would work. But the problem is that I cannot move these objects into rsc/rsc/ because the local run (without the creation of the jar-file) wouldn't work anymore...

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of use, I would recommand using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), which automatically does that when creating a jar. There's even [an Eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/).

You could also use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/).

Comment: thx, I know that this kind of tools exist. But I haven't got any experience with them and my opinion is that if eclipse provides a tool to create executable jar's, I guess it should be possible to simply add another folder to the jar without modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

I do this usually manually, in your case
jar -uf foo.jar rsc
that includes all your resources.
You can write a script or do this in ant

Answer (score 1):

As you say in **Edit 2** that you have all in one jar, this should work:

```
String path = "rsc/img/img.gif";
URL url = this.getClass().getResource(path);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have to say that "this.getClass()" is located in src/util/
Will try it