# Having trouble fetching image (newbie)

Tags: java, image, jframe

I am having trouble fetching an image to show up in my J Frame.
I am sure I put the file in the right place and have typed the name correctly.
this is the code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class DrawImage extends JFrame {
    private Image image;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new DrawImage();
    }
    public DrawImage(){
        super("DrawImage");
        setSize(600,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        File appBase = new File("."); //current directory
        String path = appBase.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(path);
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        image= tk.getImage(getURL("Castle.jpg"));
    }
    private URL getURL(String filename){
        URL url=null;
        try{
            url=this.getClass().getResource(filename);
            //url=DrawImage.class.getResource(filename);
            //url=C:\hw/myProg/Graphics2d/Castle.jpg;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("spleen:");
        }
        return url;
    }
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 40, this);
        }

}
```

What I get is the JFrame with black but no image and this write out to the cousle.

```
C:\hw\myProg\Graphics2d\.
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

naturally my image file is in C:\hw\myProg\Graphics2d\Castle.jpg So what am I doing wrong?
EDIT: OK I figured it out you can test which folder your ide complies from from this handy piece of code.  in eclipse it is in the bin folder.

```
URL test = DrawImage.class.getResource("/");
        System.out.println(test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, the Castle.jpg is NOT within the classloaders classpath context.  If the image is not Jar'ed within the application you could use a `File` object to generate the `URL`, but I don't think that's what you want to do.

You could:

- Make sure that you are executing from program file "C:\hw\myProg\Graphics2d".
- Jar the application (together with it's resources)

Comment: Ok so my image is not complied with the rest of my code that helps thanks, but could you show me how to do that? I using eclipse I did more homework on it but it showed things complied when they put in the scr folder but that did not work for me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with eclipse, but you could check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062941/build-project-into-a-jar-automatically-in-eclipse or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073250/eclipse-export-to-jar-and-include-resource-files-ant for more details