# SAX - Can't get the file path right in libGDX to parse

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax, libgdx

I'm trying to parse a xml file in a game I'm making with libGDX. I get FileNotFoundException under circumstances below.

In a class extending DefaultHandler, I have this method to parse xml under xml/data.xml. If I place this xml folder outside the src/ directory, it works within Eclipse, but not when I export it because the folder "xml" doesn't get included in jar.

Now when I put it under src folder and specify the path as "src/xml/data.xml", it works, again only within Eclipse.

How could I find the path?

```
public void loadXML() throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

    parser.parse(Gdx.files.internal("xml/data.xml").path(), this);
}
```

Comment: You're exporting a .jar to run on your desktop?  (Not exporting to Android or GWT or one of the other backends?)

Comment: Yes, I'm developing for desktop and not for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Eclipse is packaging the file into the .jar file when its in the `src/` directory (See  [Eclipse: export to .jar AND include resource files (ANT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073250/eclipse-export-to-jar-and-include-resource-files-ant)), so you first you need to switch from `Gdx.files.internal` to `Gdx.files.classpath` to look the file in the jar via the classpath.

Note that you should be able to tag the `xml/` directory as a "source folder" if you want to leave it at the top-level.

The second issue is that there is no "path" for a file stored inside a .jar.  That is there is no `String` like "/this/is/a/path/to/a/file" that can represent files inside a .jar (so the call to `.path()` on the File won't return anything useful).  You can ask for an `InputStream` or a `Reader` of such a file-in-a-jar, though.  I think [`Gdx.files.classpath("xml/data.xml").reader()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html#reader()) (or [`.read(1024)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html#read(int)))
should work (assuming there is a `SAXParser` `parse` method that takes a `Reader` (or `InputStream`).  If `SAXParser` requires a String path, you may need a different approach.

Comment: I specified the path with `Gdx.files.classpath("xml/data.xml").path()` and added the xml/ as source folder. It works in Eclipse, but not when exported. I get this exception when I run the jar.  _java.io.FileNotFoundException:C:\Users\Me\Desktop\xml\data.xml_

Comment: Ah .. I think you're running into the problem where there is no "path" to a file packaged up inside a .jar in the classpath.  You need to use a SAXParser API that expects a stream ... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793213/getting-the-inputstream-from-a-classpath-resource-xml-file

Comment: Thank you! `ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream` worked! Could you explain a little more on what was going on? What do you mean by a SAXParser API that expects a stream?

Comment: Heh, glad that works. I think I understand what's going on now.  (This libgdx classpath/file/internal stuff has always been a bit fuzzy to me.)  I've updated my answer to explain more.